# trying to acess css properties of a div using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried to access the width of a div using javascript,
but every time it is printing NaN no matter what i set it.
I am new to javascript, what is wrong with my code ?

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>hello</title>


        <style type="text/css">

      #base
      {
        width:300px;
        height:30px;
        background-color: black;
      }

      #scr
      {
        height:30px;
        width:10px;
        background-color: red;
      }

    </style>


    <script type="text/javascript">

    var magic = function()
    {
    console.log("inside magic")
    var d = document.getElementById("scr");
    var b =  d.style.width;
    console.log(b);
    b = parseInt(b);

    console.log(b);

    }


    </script>

    </head>

    <body>

    <div id="base">
    <div id = "scr" >
    </div>
    </div>

    <br>
    <button onclick="magic()">Magic</button>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @user1263375: I don't see the accepted answer using jQuery. And the answer you accepted now is the same as the one from the other question.

Comment: The style property is actually the attribute style of the element. So when you have <element style="..."> element.style is actually referencing what is contained in style. In your case, if you had ...style="width:20px;" then element.style would print 20px.

Comment: What you are wanting is not an attribute but rather a calculated property of the element itself. In this case, with plain javascript its often easiest to use width = element.offsetWidth || element.clientWidth || element.scrollHeight;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should try

```
d.offsetWidth
```

instead of

```
d.style.width
```

Comment: Why d.style.width isnt working, shoudnt it work ?

Comment: @user1263375: Because the style is not set on the element but via CSS rules.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function to do that:

```
function getStyle(el,styleProp)
{
    var x = document.getElementById(el);
    if (x.currentStyle)
        var y = x.currentStyle[styleProp];
    else if (window.getComputedStyle)
        var y = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(x,null).getPropertyValue(styleProp);
    return y;
}
```

The explanation of what's going on is [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/getstyles.html) 
Note that you must use element's id to access its style property through the function. 
If you want to use selectors use document.querySelector() in place of document.getElementById()

Comment: If both if statements don't match their conditions then this code causes an undefined error.

Answer (score -1):

The code `d.style.width` returns the width explicitly specified by css while `d.offsetWidth` returns the computed width.